# Passing variables from Controller to View in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm using the Places library and the [angular google places autocomplete](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete/) module. The autocomplete functionality works perfectly, results are being displayed and selected upon click.

What I am trying to do now is to **generate a map from the address once the user selects one of the results** of the autocomplete.

I have the following function in my controller:

```
$scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function(event, place) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { "address": place.name }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
            location = results[0].geometry.location,
                lat      = location.lat(),
                lng      = location.lng();

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }
    });
});
```

It doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure that it is because it can't access the map_canvas element from the frontend (which in itself is inside a template view).

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

How could I link the two (or pass the lat and lng variables to the frontend) to make the map appear when the user selects a result?

**EDIT**

I made a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qR8qqaidxztX6SfWCJxO?p=preview) that illustrates the error. You'll see that once you select a location, it makes a redirect, in my case to **http://localhost:9000/(1.650801,%2010.267894999999953)**, being the last part the latitude and longitude.

Comment: any chance you can add a plunkr? I'd be happy to take a look if I can edit some code...

Comment: @panzhuli check the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I adjusted a few things, mostly stylistic for my clarity. I think you had some issues with variable declaration. This now loads a map object. I'll let you futz around with making it show data :-)

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('wopWop', ['google.places']);

  app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
        $scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function(event, place) {
          var loc, lat, lng, latlng, map, options,
              geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

          geocoder.geocode( { "address": place.name }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                    loc = results[0].geometry.location,
                    lat = loc.lat(),
                    lng = loc.lng();
                  }
            });
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            options = {
               zoom: 1,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
        });
  });
})();
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/m9NWaK2IVWZAb09wDx4j?p=preview)